# nginx proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000 not working

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

What is wrong with my configuration, when I open http://management.teampapercloud.in/ I see the default nginx home page, it is not reaching my node server running at PORT 3000.

```
server {
    server_name  management.teampapercloud.in www.management.teampapercloud.in;
    listen 80;

    root /usr/share/nginx/;
    # index index.html index.htm;

    location /static {
        alias /home/ubuntu/papercloud/static;
    }   

    location /media {
        alias /home/ubuntu/papercloud/paper_cloud/paper_cloud/media;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    location / {
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin '*';
        proxy_pass_header Server;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Protocol $scheme;
        proxy_connect_timeout 50;
        proxy_read_timeout 50;

        # This line is important as it tells nginx to channel all requests to port 8000.
        # We will later run our wsgi application on this port using gunicorn.
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;

        client_max_body_size 20m;
    }

    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you restart Nginx? Test the configuration using `nginx -t`. Can you see your `server` block in the output from `nginx -T`? Check the access and error logs and include any relevant entries in your question.

Comment: Even after stopping nginx, its working. Couldnt figure out whats happening

Answer (score 1):

Make sure

- Your domain pointing to the correct server IP address.
- You have restarted the nginx service after the change.
- Look for server name typos.
- nginx.conf has include /usr/local/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
- default config in
  nginx is not overriding any of your server blocks.

Comment: Checked all of these and nothing is wrong, any tips?